# How do I get the docker client to trust a self signed cert on the token auth server

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm attempting to get a docker registry v2 set up including token auth using self signed certificates.

I can get my docker client to trust the docker registry (by adding the ca.crt into /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.example.com/ in boot2docker)

I'm not sure how to tell the docker registry v2 to trust the auth server, though. I get the following error:

```
FATA[0003] Error pushing to registry: Get 
https://docker-auth.example.com/auth?
scope=repository%3Atest%3Apull%2Cpush&service=registry.example.com: 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I'm using the docker auth server here: https://github.com/brandnetworks/docker_auth

Comment: This turned out to be a docker version issue. It started working after we switched to docker 1.8+